# Google Cloud SQL + RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS

Tags: jdbc, google-apps-script, google-cloud-sql

I've got a table in my Google Cloud SQL database with an auto-incrementing column.

How do I execute an `INSERT` query via google-apps-script/JDBC and get back the value for the newly incremented column?

For example, my column is named `ticket_id`. I want to `INSERT` and have the new `ticket_id` value be returned in the result set.

In other words, if I have the following structure, what would I need to modify or how, so that I can do something like `rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();`

```
var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection("jdbc:google:rdbms:.......  
var stmt = conn.createStatement();

//build my INSERT sql statement  
var sql = "insert into ......

var rs = stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

I see that there is a JDBC statement class with a member called `RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` but I have so far not been smart enough to figure out how to properly manipulate that and get what I need. Is `RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` a constant, is it an attribute, or how can I make use of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like the documentation with the Apps Script JDBC service is a bit lacking. I've created an internal task item for that. Thankfully, Apps Script JDBC API follows the Java JDBC API pretty closely. The key is to get the result set back using the `stmt.getGeneratedKeys()` call.

I built a sample table using the animals example from the MySQL docs and this sample below works nicely against that and logs the next incremented ID.

```
function foo() {
  var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection("jdbc:google:rdbms://<instance>/<db>");
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  var sql = "INSERT INTO animals (name) VALUES ('dog')";
  var count = stmt.executeUpdate(sql,1)//pass in any int for auto inc IDs back
  var rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
  //if you are only expecting one row back, no need for while loop
  // just do rs.next();
  while(rs.next()) { 
    Logger.log(rs.getString(1));
  }
  rs.close();
  stmt.close();
  conn.close();
}
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks Arun, worked perfectly. Although I saw the GetGeneratedKeys method in the Oracle/Java docs I didn't see it in the Google Apps Script JDBC docs so I never thought to just try it.

Comment: Arun, this fixed a problem of mine. But maybe you can give me some more information on the following:

Since yesterday stmt.getGeneratedKeys(); failed with the error:

Generated keys not requested. You need to specify Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS to Statement.executeUpdate() or Connection.prepareStatement().

After I changed stmt.prepareStatement(sql) tot stmt.prepareStatement(sql,1) it worked again.

Has anything changed yesterday that made the missing int fail AND is this the right trick?